# python - UTC minus 15 minutes in 13 digit timestamp format

Tags: python-2.7

I have scratched my brains enough to find my last resort here . I am calling an API which takes values like below for the lastUpdatedTime paramter :

lastUpdatedTime : 1499591547769

lastUpdatedTime : 1499591547770

So i assume the above values are converted to miliseconds since there are 13 digits (1499591547770 & 1499591547769).

Below is what i want to do in simple english .

- Get the UTC time now and subtract 15 minutes from it .
- Send that value to the API and fetch the data.

My problem is time conversion .

Below is what i am doing in python.

```
 update_time = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') 

   update_time_check = (calendar.timegm(time.strptime(update_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')))*1000
```

The value for the above is something like **1502247759000**

When i send that value (lastUpdatedTime = 1502247759000) to the API , i get a blank result set .

Please let me know if my steps are correct in generating the timestamp which the API is expecting .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any chance that the API you're calling is not using / expecting UTC?

Comment: No it is...at least thats what mentioned in the documentation...